# Finding imperfect straight lines in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, filtering, hough-transform

My task is to find out all the green shoots from random bush like this one

[image]

Using color segmentation and blob analysis i have obtained a contour plot of the image. To find shoots from the contour plots i used Hough transforms but they end up giving a number of false positives. I have tried tuning the parameters of both Hough lines and peaks but it either results in a number of false positives or false negatives for different images. Here is the code snippet

```
  [H,theta,rho] = hough(BW,'Theta',-90:1:89,'rhoResolution',1);
P = houghpeaks(H,100,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))),'NhoodSize',[21 21]);
lines = houghlines(BW,theta,rho,P,'FillGap',15,'MinLength',100);
```

This is the output i get : [image]

can some point me to a better way to do this ?

Comment: How are you segmenting the color? I'm guessing right now you're thresholding on the G channel. It looks like you have some white petals that remained in your image. You could probably get rid of those by filtering for areas where G is greater than R and B by some (experimentally determined) amount. That might help a little bit.

Comment: Yes. Right now we are using thresholding on R channel. But the desired shoots are also green are similar to leaves. So segmentation there would not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea, but it's too long for me to throw it into a comment.

You could identify and label connected components in the contour plot image and then check the different components to see if it's long and thin or more blob-like. There are probably a bunch of ways to test that. The first that comes to mind is comparing the connected component to a line that runs diagonally across the component's bounding rectangle. (But check it both ways.)  You would probably want to generate the mask for each bounding box you come across that is something like this:

```
 1  1 -1 -1 -1
-1  1  1  1 -1
-1 -1 -1  1  1
```

...and also the mirror image of it.  Obviously, you would need to play around with it a bit.  You could add some smoothing to the mask so that it has more tolerance for things that aren't perfectly straight. The principle, though, is that the mask is by-element multiplied with the subimage containing the component in question. The sum of all the elements in the resulting matrix gives you a score that tells you how line-like it is. If you are using a variable sized mask, then you also need to normalize the scores somehow. This might fail on lines that are parallel to the axes, but those are easy enough to test for because the bounding box for the component will be long and thin.

Failing that, you could try convolving a set of masks of lines at various angles to measure the line-likeness at any given point in the image, but that's probably going to be more work and less robust.